# Can I use .py file instead of .ini file on alembic?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, migration, alembic

I want to use alembic.py for configuration instead of alembic.ini.
But I can't find any example of that type of configuration.
Is there any way to not use alembic.ini?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for [this](http://alembic.readthedocs.org/en/rel_0_7/api.html#configuration):

```
from alembic.config import Config
alembic_cfg = Config()
alembic_cfg.set_main_option("script_location", "myapp:migrations")
alembic_cfg.set_main_option("url", "postgresql://foo/bar")
alembic_cfg.set_section_option("mysection", "foo", "bar")
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. How can I specify this custom config `.py` file when execute alembic command?

Comment: Save this file as `alembic_config_file.py` and import it from your application in the beginning.

Comment: Also please consider [upvoting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) or marking it answer by clicking the tick if it helped you.

Comment: The new document Url can be found at https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/api/config.html